# ActionBarSherlock not working in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying to get ActionBarSherlock ( http://www.actionbarsherlock.com ) working with my eclipse projects. I added ABS into a new project with target version 3.2, and this created fine. When I try to add this as a library to my other project (min version 2.1, target 3.2), I get errors such as

```
G:\EclipseWorkspace\Android\ActionBarSherlock2\res\values-v11\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'
```

basically, none of the xml attributes found in 3.0 or higher are recognised. As a consequence, R.java does not generate.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile with Android 3.2 in addition to targeting at least API 11 both in your app and for the library.

In eclipse, right click on the project and go to "Properties". Under the "Android" tab you'll need to select Android 3.2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the documentation was unclear, I thought that you set 3.2 as a target and kept the build target as the minimum version. Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is giving me strange Errors too, when implementing external libraries. What always helped for me after some tries:

try multiple times:

*rightclick on your project => Source => Clean Up
*delete and readd the library project
*restart eclipse several

you might also try to delete the generated files to force it to regenerate, but do this on your own risk :)

have fun w/ the open source libraries :)

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading the version of the sdk and target version 2.1:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

This will allow using last sdk features and the app will work on version 2.1.

Maybe, you'll see issues even after fixing this. Then you can clean the project.